# Estimate the probability that N random 4-digit pin numbers are all distinct for N=10, 1000, 100

Tags: probability, birthday

As per title, the question is "estimate the probability that N random 4-digit pin numbers are all distinct for N=10, 1000, 100".

My current working is as follows:

There are $10^{4}$ total 0-10 4 digit combinations. For N pin numbers, this means a total of $10000^{N}$ total possibilities.

Next, for all pin numbers to be unique, you are essentially sampling without replacement, meaning for the first pin you have $10000$ possibilities, $10000 - 1$ for the second, etc, giving:

\begin{equation}
\frac{10000 \cdot (10000-1) \cdot (10000-2) ...(10000-N+1)}{10000^{N}}
\end{equation}

Does this seem sensible? The next step of possibly working this out by hand I am a bit lost on though. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What tools do you have at your disposal for calculating by hand? Would Stirling's Approximation help?

Comment: I believe that the numerator here should be a combination number: ie how many ways we can draw N numbers out of 10^4. In that sense, isn't there N! missing in the denominator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that numerator is $\frac{10000!}{(10000 - N)!}$. As stated by @InterstellarProbe, you can apply the stirling approximation to the denominator and continue from there. 
[Stirling formula](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirlingformel)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct so far. So now the difficulty is estimating the numerator, namely the three products $10000 \cdots 9991$, $10000 \cdots 9901$, $10000 \cdots 9001$. In other words, you're looking for $10000!/9990!, 10000!/9900!, 10000!/9000!$.

Factorials can be approximated using some variant of [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Alternatively, if you don't want to use that, you can still get the rough order of magnitude of your values by using the fact that the product of a set of $k$ numbers is equal to the $k$-th power of its geometric mean, and in these cases the geometric mean is very close to the arithmetic mean, so you can just take the $k$-th power of the arithmetic mean as an approximation, and it will still fall within an order of magnitude of the actual value.